# Grid computing: how to redistribute calculation to optimise response time

Tags: optimization

I have set up an infrastructure for grid computation. That is, an operation of N iterations is distributed and independently calculated on different servers, and the final result is the aggregation of the individual results.

Each server has a different number of CPU cores. Each core operates independently.

I have three servers: S1, S2, S3.

- S1 has 4 cores.
- S2 has 8 cores.
- S3 has 4 cores.

So, in total, 16 cores.

Say I have an operation of 500.000 iterations, I distribute the calculation in the following way:

- S1 => (500.000 / 16 * 4) = 125.000 iterations
- S2 => (500.000 / 16 * 8) = 250.000 iterations
- S3 => (500.000 / 16 * 4) = 125.000 iterations

Now the response times:

- S1 completes 125.000 iterations in 4587 ms.
- S2 completes 250.000 iterations in 8403 ms.
- S3 completes 125.000 iterations in 9356 ms.

As you can see the servers have different performances: S3 is more than twice slower than S1.

What I want is to redistribute the calculation in a non uniform way, so that the response time is optimised (for example, S3 should be assigned approximately half of the iterations than S1).

What's the math behind this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r_s$ be the number of iterations per ms for server $s$.  Let decision variable $x_s$ be the number of iterations assigned to server $s$.  You want to minimize the *makespan*
$$\max_{s\in\{1,2,3\}} x_s/r_s$$
subject to
\begin{align}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &= 500000 \tag1 \\
x_s &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $s$}
\end{align}
The optimal value will occur when $$x_1/r_1 = x_2/r_2 = x_3/r_3. \tag2$$  Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields $x \approx (193646, 211414, 94940)$.

Comment: So brilliant. Thanks!